# Honeywell home ventilation system with no c wire for thermostat. How can I substitute the g for the c without blowing a fuse?

Tags: thermostat

I'm hoping to get some help with my thermostat problem. We bought our home brand new and it came with a very basic thermostat (non programmable and runs on batteries). I want to upgrade it to a wifi programmable thermostat so I bought a honeywell one. Our home has a honeywell ventilation system that pulls fresh air from the outside and circulates it through the home. [image][image][image][image]As I read the instructions to use the g wire for the c wire it seemed easy enough. I am handy enough that I finished my own basement electrical and all do I figured it can't be too hard. 
So I pulled the old thermostat off after labeling the wires. Put in the new wifi one and used the g wire for the c. Went to my furnace and I have wires running all over. [image][image]Into the furnace from upstairs is just a 4 wire[image], I have no extras. All wires are connected to the furnace board except the g wire is connected to a wire that runs up to the honeywell ventilation system and then another set of wires returns back to the furnace board. 
I figured out which of the return wires is the g wire and attempted to move that to the c wire in the furnace board then out a jumper in between the y and g on the same board. At first I thought this made it work because I was able to setup the wifi thermostat because it was receiving power. I setup the wifi and set the temp and the ac kicked on so I figured I was good to go. About 10 minutes later though the power to the thermostat was gone and I blew the 3amp fuse in the box. I tested it again and sure enough, after 10 minutes the new fuse blew. 
can anyone help me understand what is going wrong and what I need to do to fix it so I can use my new thermostat?  I did call the person that installed my system and he didn't seem too thrilled about answering my questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're out of luck, since the `G` wire passes through the ventilation control system.  You have to leave the `G` wire as a `G` wire, or remove/bypass the ventilation system. The easiest solution, would be to run a new 5 wire cable. Or don't use a fancy thermostat.

If you follow the `G` wire through the system, you can get a better picture of what's going on.

[image: G wire through the system]

When the thermostat energizes the `G` terminal, the `Gt` terminal on the ventilation control receives the signal.  The ventilation control does whatever it does, and eventually energizes the `Gf` terminal. When the `Gf` terminal is energized on the ventilation control, the furnace receives the signal and starts the blower.

From what I can tell based on the images, this is what the whole system looks like.

[image: Whole System]

<sub>*On a side note. The installer that left that rats nest of wiring in the furnace, should be ashamed of himself.*</sub>

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thank you for the response and help. I hadn't really worked with wiring before but I'm glad to know that it really is a mess of wires because that's what it looked like to me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The picture below you would pull the green wire off of Green at both the stat and furnace and move it to C/Common, then  you jumper Yellow to Green at the furnace.